# Riemann Sum / Definite Integral question

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

I am looking at the definition of a definite integral in terms of the limit of a Riemann Sum.

Do the widths of the partitions become 0 as the number of partitions approaches infinity?

Comment: Think what happens when one partition covers half of the interval and the rest of them shrink (and increase in number). And look up spelling of names, it's not that difficult.

Comment: The width of the majority of the parts in a partition will *approach* zero (*but not "become zero"*), yes, but as mentioned it need not necessarily be the case that *all* parts have widths approaching zero.

Comment: The definition of Riemann integral is pretty standard and available in most textbooks of analysis. One popular definition deals with something called norm or mesh of a partition. This norm/mesh is defined as the width of largest sub-interval made by the partition. And when dealing with Riemann integrals the essential part is that the mesh of the partition should tend to $0$. In this case the number of sub-intervals automatically tends to infinity. But note that reverse does not happen and hence the integral is not defined as a limit when number of sub-intervals tends to infinity.